# Twitter bootstrap-modal for images

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, lightbox

I have a page which includes details of the registered users.
Every html table includes 80-90 users.
For every user there is a $username variable.
I normally show their pictures in a table like the code below.

```
print "<a href=\"small-avatar-$username.jpg\" target=\"_blank\">
<img src=\"big-avatar-$username.jpg\">
</a>";
```

But the user can open images in a new tab. I want to show big avatars easily.
My first choice was **lightbox-jquery**. But because i use **twitter-bootstrap** in my site, i decided to use default bootstrap and jquery features.

I saw that there is "bootstrap-modals". When user clicks link, i don't plan to show anything more than i big picture.

I tried this:

```
print "<a href=\"#$username" data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"img-modal\" >
        <img src=\"small-avatar-$username.jpg\" ></a>";
print '</td>';
```

.

```
print "<div id=\"$username\" class=\"modal\">";
       <img src=\"big-avatar-$username.jpg\">
print "</div>";
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="js">
        $('#username').modal();
</script>
```

I suppose putting `$('#username').modal();`
for every user to my page will make HTML file huge.

But then I tried class name of anchor like this: `$('.img-modal').modal();`
But this didn't work.

What would you recommend in this situation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) in your `<a>` tag to identify the username and keep your `img-modal` class.

```
"<a href="#myModal" data-username='".$username."' class="img-modal">...
```

Trigger the call to modal on click on .img-modal (you don't need the data-toggle="modal")

```
$('.img-modal').click(function(event) {
```

You can get the value of the username by using

```
var username = $(this).attr('data-username')
```

Since you have the username you can replace the `src` property of your `<img>` tag in your unique modal with something like.

```
$("#img-in-modal").attr("src","big-avatar-" + username + ".jpg")
```

And open your modal

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

And finally, make sure bootstrap-modal.js or boostrap.js is included.

Comment: An alternative to access data-* attributes would be `$(this).data('username')`.